# Generate class or interface from the literal type?

Tags: typescript

How to generate the following interface

```
const fn = (v: string) => console.log(v)
class Methods {
  a: fn
  b: fn
}
```

given the literal type for keys

```
type Keys = 'a' | 'b'
const KeysList = ['a', 'b']
```

something like

```
const fn = (v: string) => console.log(v)
class Methods {
  [key in Keys] = fn
}    
new Methods().a("something")
```

The reason is that there are couple of tens of keys, all have the same implementation, so it would be nice to specify it with expression instead of writing the actual code.

Comment: How do you have the keys ? Do you have them in an array or as the keys to another object ? We can get the types to work out, but adding the values to the object requires having the keys in value space in some way

Comment: you'd have an easier time going the other way. declare the interface and make your type `keyof Methods`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yes, good point, the list of keys also available as array, I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function that returns a constructor that returns `Record<Keys,  (v: string) => void>`. We can then call this function in the extends clause of the new class.

```
const KeysList = ['a', 'b'] as const
type Keys = typeof KeysList[number]


function extendWithKeys<K extends string, V>(keys: readonly K[], value: V): new () => Record<K, V> {
  return class {
    constructor() {
      for (let key of keys) {
        (this as any)[key] = value;
      }
    }
  } as new () => Record<K, V> 
}

const fn = (v: string) => console.log(v)
class Methods extends extendWithKeys(KeysList, fn) {

}    
new Methods().a("something")
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=20&ssc=29&pln=2&pc=1#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAaQKYE8oBkCWs4F44DaA5AIZEA0cRARkQLpwlRzjQzAwoAOSiqz+TjzAAzPmiywCEAK4BbakgBOdYGpEyIIGJkhwkADxhIIAEwDqmGAAtkaADwJ9Rk6eawlmCAHNKANQA+AAoAa34ALjglJBJTSAAbFEQCOkoANxJ4mSRIvwBKSIgkAHc4ILy8ALgAJSRwJVNHfyqAb2A4KKQYGSUIFnimZjaOjtYPGW0wJXK4YZGOkSmy+K64MKTRNf4KufmOoJtsRmYSCBQ8gnWGfAyspABudr2AXyeO1-fjuCLSmdwq2r1RoIZpwYCvUCQHAiPr4IJpSIeLzeCr-FhQsArAB08TA3nheVAAygzAAsl1rGA3M5jGZmIZaRYrLZ+EE7BhsDBKDCdk9wfNgD84OSbFSoOUsSQggAiKBgOQU5HSvJAA)